# mongorestore on replicsets from non-replicated DB instance

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 environments(say A and B). MongoDb on A is running without replication and on B replication is setup with following replicaset instances

> **B1** - *Primary*
>   **B2** - *secondary*
>   **B3** - *arbiter*

I have taken the dump from A instance and restored successfully on B relicasets.

```
mongorestore --host rs/b1,b2 --drop
```

However when I stop the mongo instances on B and reboot primary, secondary and arbiter instances, replication gets corrupted. I get following error when checked **rs.status()** for either arbiter or secondary instances. I am wondering does mongorestore on replicated environment from non-replicated environment is supported or not.

```
lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us",
```

Morevoever before rebooting servers I have run **db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()** on secondary to check if sync is successful or not. Here is what I got and **rs.status()** was ok too

```
source: x.x.x.x:27017
    syncedTo: Tue Mar 13 2018 07:44:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
rs0:SECONDARY>
```

Comment: If you are using `mongodump` to backup data from deployment A you should be able to `mongorestore` into deployment B (replica set) irrespective of the original topology. I suspect your replication issue is unrelated to the backup & restore: the error message indicates that a replica set member cannot find its own hostname in the replica set config. Using the `mongo` shell can you check the output of `hostname()` versus `rs.conf()`? It would also be helpful to know your specific versions of O/S and MongoDB server.

Comment: hostname() gives ip-x.x.x.x.us-west-1.compute.internal where as in rs.config() i have given elastic ips. And it is able to communicate each other, working properly and even failing over if primary goes down but only to get corrupt after next reboot. 
`Mongo shell and DB version - 3.2.3`